# How to implement a Kotlin function to a View

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to know how to implement functions to a ConstraintLayout in Kotlin.

I need something like this:

```
fun applyCustomPropeties(){
    //some stuff
}

val rootLayout = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.rootLayout)

rootLayout.applyCustomPropeties()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an extension function:

```
fun ConstraintLayout.applyCustomProperties() {
    //some stuff
    //you can use "this" keyword here
}
```

That extension is resolved "statically", so no matter where you put that code. Now, you can do what you want:

```
val rootLayout = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.rootLayout)
rootLayout.applyCustomPropeties()
```